# Quicktime playback delay on windows

Tags: windows, video, quicktime

I'm building an app which needs high playback performance.
I choose Quicktime as video engine.
I experimented different playback performance with different version:

- v7.1.3 has the best performance : when pressing play in the QT player, the video starts immediatly
- newer quicktime release have very poor playback performance, the delay between pressing play and the effective video playback is about 400ms.
  Is there a way to improve this latency in the latest release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally processed the sound with a custom library and used QuickTime only for video display in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're seeing precaching. Can you adjust the cache settings?